# Consume events from AWS EventBridge in a self hosted kafka cluster outsite aws

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-event-bridge

We got a SaaS which is publishing it's events on AWS eventbridge (coulple of milion per day). We would love to consume those events and put them on our self hosted Kafka cluster. What would be the best methode to do this? We where thinking about lambda's, but the seem expensive for this use case and we don't to to manage to many other components. Does anyone have some good practices?

Answer (score 2):

i was looking for a similar solution but in my case it is from eventbridge to MSK within AWS account. at this point looks like the only option is to use a lambda to feed into Kafka.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As per today, AWS only supports following Targets - https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-targets.html#eb-console-targets

I have a similar use case where i need to send a message to AWS RabbitMQ or even to AWS Kafka as i need Priority Logic Implemented.

As AWS supports Lambda's, the message can be forwarded to the lambda from where it can be fed to any system